# Fetching JSON into an NSArray for dynamic navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsjsonserialization

Say I have a JSON object as such:

```
{"data":[{"stuff":[
    {"onetype":[
        {"id":1,"name":"John Doe"},
        {"id":2,"name":"Don Joeh"}
    ]},
    {"othertype":[
        {"id":2,"company":"ACME"}
    ]}]
},{"otherstuff":[
    {"thing":
        [[1,42],[2,2]]
    }]
}]}
```

How could I read it in so I can access it like so:

```
result.data[0].stuff[0].onetype[0]
```

I have tried the following:

```
NSData *rawJSONdata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:someURL];
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:rawJSONdata options:0 error:&error];
```

But this gets me an `NSArray` with only 1 empty object.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but as a helper, you really shouldn't use: `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:` anymore.

Comment: @Mark, @troop231 is right—Apple recommends `dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:` for network requests in the documentation for the method you're currently using. Now back to your question—have you checked the contents of `rawJSONdata` to make sure it has the correct JSON?

Comment: First thing you have to do is recognize that you have a dictionary, not an array.  Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax, then understand that a JSON array matches an NSArray, while a JSON "object" matches an NSDictionary.

Answer (score 2):

#### To keep it simple and keep using NSJSONSerialization, you should be able to access the data using the following syntax:

```
result[@"data"][0][@"stuff"][0][@"onetype"][0]
```

I am guessing that the problem you're seeing is related to the fact that because your JSON's outermost type is an Object not an Array, the result in your example is an NSDictionary, not an NSArray.  You'll need to change your parse code to:

```
NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:rawJSONdata options:0 error:&error];
```

#### In order to use the exact syntax you proposed:

The best way I know of would be a JSON-to-Object mapping framework.  I can't find a fully automated solution for Objective-C (Java has a solution called [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)), but [JTObjectMapping](https://github.com/jamztang/JTObjectMapping) is an Objective-C framework that provides a manual ability to convert an NSDictionary to Object.

NSJSONSerialization, though, will always use the following mappings:

- array (aka `[ ]`) <=> NSArray
- object (aka `{ }`) <=> NSDictionary
- number <=> NSNumber
- string <=> NSString
- `true`/`false` <=> NSNumber
- `null` <=> NSNull